# Браузер сам создает теги, которые я не создаю

Tags: html

Здраствуйте! Верстаю простенький сайт и время от времени поглядываю в панель элементов в браузере. И, как бы это странно не звучало, но у меня создаются теги `<a> </a>` внутри которых абсолютно неизвестным мне образом записываются мои блоки. Привожу **HTML**:

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav_btn">MENU<a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_btn">OUR STORY<a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_btn_logo">Eudora<a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_btn">OFFER<a>
            <a href="#" class="nav_btn">CONTACT<a>
        </div>
        <div class="text">
            <p class="text_content">Eudora is simply psd template</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

И вот, как это видит браузер:

[image: Проблема]

Тестировал в Chrome и Edge - результат один и тот же.

Уверен проблема до безумия легко решается, но, как всегда бывает, не для меня. Буду благодарен за объяснения почему так происходит

Comment: браузер помогает вам закрывать теги))) тег `a` является парным и требует закрытия - `<a>Ссылка</a>`

Comment: Блин, да, действительно. Создавал много тегов через еммет и чет перемудрил. Спасибо вам!

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/